# SSH Key is refused when on other systems

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, putty

I created a new ssh keypair on my Windows system for my Ubuntu server, which I hoped could be used on other systems. I run `ssh-keygen` on my windows system, which creates a `.pem` and `.pub` file, and used `puttygen` to convert the `.pem` file to the `.ppk` file. I add the public key to my ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and I'm able to login using Putty on my Windows system.

When I use my private key (either .pem of .ppk) on another system (for example Mac of my neighbor), the server refuses my private key. I have no clue what could cause this error and tried several things already.

ppk looks as follows:

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: none
Comment: name
Public-Lines: 12
xxxxxx
Private-Lines: 28
xxxxxx
Private-MAC: xxxxxx
```

pem looks as follows:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxxxx
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

pub looks as follows:

```
ssh-rsa xxxxxx name
```

And the only line I get in the log file is the following:

```
Mar 26 11:29:29 name-of-server sshd[4421]: Connection closed by <ip-address> port 58439 [preauth]
```

Comment: Show us log files of uses of your private key on both machines.

Comment: The PEM file created by putty, needs to be exported to be able to be used on a linux machine - the format putty uses doesn't match the format needed on a linux machine.

Comment: Also the permissions need to be correct, once you've copied it into the correct directory.

Comment: @djsmiley2k PuTTY uses PPK, not PEM. Though OP should indeed be more clear PPK: *"using puttygen I **create** the .ppk file"* is ambiguous. I assume that PuTTYgen was used to **convert** PEM to PPK, not to **create** a new PPK key. - OP please make it clear.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I added the log output.

Comment: @djsmiley2k I updated my question, I indeed converted my .pem file to a .ppk file.

Comment: I mean client-side log (though *verbose* server-side log can be useful too, if you are able to obtain it).

Comment: If you are generating keys on Windows for use with PuTTY, you can use PuTTYgen straight way to generate it. No need to use `ssh-keygen` first. Though that's just a side note. The result is the same.

Comment: Client-side: `Mar 26 13:45:44 Names-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.preference.displays.MirrorDisplays): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.`

Comment: What is it? That's not a PuTTY log, neither `ssh` log. We need PuTTY log and log of the SSH client that you are using on the "other" machine.

Comment: Please test again from the macbook, in a terminal window. Use ssh-add first, then connect with ssh in verbose mode (option -v)